# want to install java in folder other than default

Tags: java, ubuntu

I want to install Java in the folder /java/bin so that

```
 which java
```

should return

```
/java/bin/java
```

I am using ubuntu 11.04. Currently it shows after default installation

```
  #which java
    /usr/bin/java
```

Is there any alternative way?